# Getting values(Statically created and stored in java class) from server side using Angularjs

Tags: javascript, java, html, angularjs

Here are my codes. where i have html part which is working properly as well as Angularjs Controller(controller gives the response in form of a list available inside itself)
but when i try to get a list from server side where list is present statically in java class i am not able to do so as i have a apiServices.js which have a method(2 parameters one is module and other is parameter to interact with server side(i just want to get only list so i don't have to pass parameter value other than null).

```js
//apiService.js this will call the contents in server side java class
app.service('apiService', ['$http', '$q', 'appSettings', function ($http, $q, appSettings) {

    var apiService = {};
    var apiBase = appSettings.apiBase;
    //===========================GET RESOURCE==============================
    var get = function (module, parameter) {
        alert("service");
           var deferred = $q.defer();
        alert("service2");
           $http.get(apiBase + module, { params: parameter }, { headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' } }).success(function (response) {
             alert("response");
            deferred.resolve(response);
           }).catch(function (data, status, headers, config) { // <--- catch instead error
               deferred.reject(data.statusText);
           });

           return deferred.promise;
    };
```

```html
<section class="content-header">
       
        <ol class="breadcrumb">
            <li><a href="#/app/dashboard"><i class="fa fa-dashboard"></i> Dashboard</a></li>
            <li><a>Catalog Management</a></li>
   <li class="active">Product Management</li>
        </ol>
    </section>
 
 <div style="margin-top:15px;">
         <div class="text-right" style="margin-right: 18px;">
     <button type="button" class="btn btn-info">Import Employees</button>
     <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Import Format</button>
     
       <!-- <a ui-sref="productmanagement">Go To Product</a>  -->
  </div>
    </div>
 <section class="content" style="padding-top:20px; position:relative;">
<div class="table-header">
        <ol class="list-inline pull-right">
   <li>
    <a>
     <i class="fa fa-refresh" aria-hidden="true" ng-click="refresh()"></i>
    </a>
   </li>
   <li>
    <a>
    <a ui-sref="productmanagementsarvesh" class="btn btn-info">separate product list</a>
     <div class="btn btn-info" ng-click="addproductmanagement()">
     <Span><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></span>Add Product
     </div>
    </a>
   </li>

        </ol>
  <span class="titletable">Product Management</span>
    </div>
    <div  ui-grid="gridOptions"  ui-grid-pagination id="grid" style="height:500px"></div>
       
   
   </section>
   
   
   <script type="text/ng-template" id="action.html">
       <div class="ui-grid-cell-contents">
    <table>
    <tr><a href="#/app/product-viewuser"><i class="fa fa-eye" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></tr>&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <tr><a href="#/app/product-edituser"><i aria-hidden="true" class="fa fa-pencil-square-o"></i></a></tr>&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <tr><a href=""><i class="fa fa-trash" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></tr>
 </table>
      </div>
    </script>
```

```js
//here i have to call the get method from //apiService
dashboard.controller("productctrl", ['$rootScope', '$scope', '$state', '$location', 'dashboardService', 'Flash','$window',
function ($rootScope, $scope, $state, $location, dashboardService, Flash, $window) {
 

 $scope.myData=[{productName:"Product 1",products_type: "Internal Doors",image_name:"Image 1",image_type:"png",supplier_name:"John Smith",status:"Active",created_date:"06-14-2016"},{productName:"Product 2",products_type: "Stair Parts",image_name:"Image 2",image_type:"jpg",supplier_name:"Alex Wynn",status:"Active",created_date:"06-1-2016"},{productName:"Product 3",products_type: "Hardware",image_name:"Image 3",image_type:"psd",supplier_name:"Mike Johnson",status:"Active",created_date:"05-28-2016"},{productName:"Product 4",products_type: "Moulding",image_name:"Image 4",image_type:"gif",supplier_name:"Marcos Cevasco",status:"Inactive",created_date:"05-20-2016"},{productName:"Product 5",products_type: "Exterior Doors",image_name:"Image 5",image_type:"ai",supplier_name:"Zach Dennis",status:"Inactive",created_date:"05-15-2016"},{productName:"Product 6",products_type: "Hardware",image_name:"Image 6",image_type:"cdr",supplier_name:"Jack Daniel",status:"Active",created_date:"05-10-2016"},{productName:"Product 7",products_type: "Exterior Doors",image_name:"Image 7",image_type:"gif",supplier_name:"Mark Joyner",status:"Inactive",created_date:"05-08-2016"},{productName:"Product 8",products_type: "Moulding",image_name:"Image 8",image_type:"jpg",supplier_name:"Andriana Blow",status:"Active",created_date:"05-06-2016"},{productName:"Product 9",products_type: "Internal Doors",image_name:"Image 9",image_type:"ai",supplier_name:"Helaine Garvey",status:"Active",created_date:"05-02-2016"},{productName:"Product 10",products_type: "Stair Parts",image_name:"Image 10",image_type:"psd",supplier_name:"Sarah Alade ",status:"Inactive",created_date:"05-01-2016"}]; 
 
 // Here i am trying to write the method to set module and parameter of get variable written in apiServices.
 /*function fetchAllProducts(){ 
  apiService.get(module('productmanagement'), null)
  .then(
    function(products){
   myData=products;
   alert("taking list");
  },
  function(errResponse) {
   console.error("Error while fetching Data");
   }
  );
 };*/
 
 
 
 $scope.gridOptions = { 
     data :'myData',
     cellEditableCondition: true,
     enableFiltering: true,
 paginationPageSizes: [10, 20, 30],
    paginationPageSize: 10,
            rowHeight: 40,
       onRegisterApi: function(gridApi){
      $scope.gridApi = gridApi;
      $scope.gridApi.grid.registerRowsProcessor( $scope.singleFilter, 200 ); 
    }
  }
    
     $scope.gridOptions.columnDefs=[
   { name:'productName',displayName:'Products Name1'},
   { name: 'products_type',displayName: 'Products Type'},
   { name: 'image_name',displayName: 'Image Name'},
      { name: 'image_type',displayName: 'Image Type'},
      { name: 'supplier_name',displayName: 'Supplier Name'},
      { name: 'status',displayName: 'Status'},
      { name: 'created_date',displayName: 'Created Date'},
   { name:'Action',displayName:'Action', cellTemplate:'action.html', enableFiltering: false,}
 
    ]
 
 //refresh page  
  $scope.refresh = function(){
   location.reload();
   fetchAllProducts();
 alert("inside pm.js/refresh/afterFetchAP ")
  }
/* 
 $scope.gridOptions.onRegisterApi=function(gridApi){
      $scope.gridApi= gridApi;
     }  */
 //refresh page  

 
// add contractor model open
 $scope.open = function() {
    $scope.form_title = "Add Contractor";
    $('#myModal').modal('show');
    alert("inside pm.js/add contractor/modal/show ")
   } 
    
/*  
$scope.filter = function() {
$scope.gridApi.grid.refresh();
fetchAllUsers();

  };*/
    
  $scope.singleFilter = function( renderableRows ){
   alert("inside pm.js/singleFilter/rendering ")
    var matcher = new RegExp($scope.filterValue);
    renderableRows.forEach( function( row ) {
      var match = false;
      [ 'productName', 'products_type', 'image_name' ,'image_type', 'supplier_name','status','created_date'].forEach(function( field ){
        if (row.entity[field].match(matcher) ){
          match = true;
        }
      });
      if ( !match ){
        row.visible = false;
      }
    });
    return renderableRows;
  };
   
  
 /*  $scope.contractordetail = function()
  {
   
   $window.location.href = "#/app/gallery";
   
  }  */
$scope.addproductmanagement = function()
  {
   
   $window.location.href = "#/app/product-adduser";
  } 

}]);
```

//this is my java class where i am creating a list to be displayed later using //angularjs apiService and angularjs Controller.

```
    public class ItsAHelper {

/*
 * Responsible to interact with Hibernate Data repository to get all
 * Products list.
 * 
 */

public List<ProductDTO> getAllProductList() {

    /*
     * TODO - we have populated DTO with hard code list - later on
     * will communicate with data layer to fetch records from DB
     */

    /*
     * Calling setProductDto method with parameters to create DTO and added it to products list
     * 
     */
    List<ProductDTO> products = new ArrayList<ProductDTO>();

    products.add(setProductDto(1l, 2l, "Rock", "Sand", 10l, "soho", "sng", 12l, "Brockers", true, new Date(),
            new Date()));
    products.add(setProductDto(1l, 2l, "Rock1", "Sand1", 11l, "soho1", "sng1", 22l, "Brockers1", true, new Date(),
            new Date()));
    products.add(setProductDto(1l, 2l, "Rock2", "Sand2", 12l, "soho2", "sng2", 32l, "Brockers2", true, new Date(),
            new Date()));
    products.add(setProductDto(1l, 2l, "Rock3", "Sand3", 13l, "soho3", "sng3", 42l, "Brockers3", true, new Date(),
            new Date()));
    products.add(setProductDto(1l, 2l, "Rock4", "Sand4", 14l, "soho4", "sng4", 52l, "Brockers4", true, new Date(),
            new Date()));

    /*
     * Before returning the list we have to check for Null. This will check
     * the product list. If it is Either Empty or null. It will throw a
     * NullPointerException. If it is Neither Empty nor null then it will
     * return the list of Product
     */
    Iterator<ProductDTO> iterator = products.iterator();
    if (iterator.hasNext())
        return products;
    else
        return null;

}

// Responsible to create new productDTO with all parameters that are passed through method. as
// well as providing setter for setting the parameters which will be use to
// add values to product list.
private ProductDTO setProductDto(Long productId, Long productTypeId, String productName, String productType,
        Long imageId, String imageName, String imageType, Long supplierId, String supplierName, Boolean status,
        Date createdDate, Date lastModifiedDate) {
    ProductDTO dto = new ProductDTO();
    dto.setProductId(productId);
    dto.setProductTypeId(productTypeId);
    dto.setProductName(productName);
    dto.setProductType(productType);
    dto.setImageId(imageId);
    dto.setImageName(imageName);
    dto.setImageType(imageType);
    dto.setSupplierId(supplierId);
    dto.setSupplierName(supplierName);
    dto.setStatus(status);
    dto.setCreatedDate(createdDate);
    dto.setLastModifiedDate(lastModifiedDate);

    return dto;

}
```

}

Comment: What exact error are you getting? Also have you tested your API in isolation? Are you getting the required data when you call your API using fiddler or postman?

Comment: Well i am not able to fetch my list and other data which was available is also gone if i want to add any method.

Answer (score 1):

I can see a few issues in your code

1. `apiService` is not injected in your dahsboard controller. You need to inject the service in the dashboard to be able to use it.
2. Are your variables `dashboard` and `app` refer to the same Angular module? If no then you need to inject the dashboard module in the app module.
3. When you are assigning the list that you are getting from the service, you are simply using the `myData` variable but you should be using `$scope.myData`.
4. You have written a function `module('productmanagement')` to get the URL to the API, but I don't see that implemented in your controller? Where are you writing that function?

Comment: 1.Can you please give me an example of how to inject apiService into 'dashboard' controller(actually it is 'productctrl' controller)                               2.No sir dashboards(productmanagement is its name) angular module is 'productctrl' and for app it is 'app'.

Comment: 3.I did use $scope.myData but that is for a static list present in code given already.                                                                                                            4. module('productmanagement') is what i tried to assign the name to module along with passing parameter as null(as i have to get all values of list). and i think that is wrong way. so can you please provide me something which actually calls get variable from apiService.